# Resizing a cell with iOS8

Tags: uitableview, ios8, autolayout

I have a custom cell which I want to resize it when is tapped.

The cell is created by XIB and the cell comprises a subview. I've set all autolayout rules and it's working fine at beginning.

[image: Cell xib]

I've set my table view with the estimatedHight:

```
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0;
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
```

I've created a NSLayoutConstraint which changes the subview height.

I've created a button and in the method (inside of the cell) I make modify the constant of that constraint:

```
 - (IBAction)expandCollapseCell:(id)sender {

    self.mainLabelViewHeightContraint.constant = 150;
    [self setNeedsLayout];
    [self layoutIfNeeded];
}
```

Instead of autoresize my cell, that breaks my autolayout rules:

```
translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fba8a786080 UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fba8a76b5e0.bottomMargin == UIView:0x7fba8a7c3490.bottom - 1>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fba8a786120 UIView:0x7fba8a7c3490.top == UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fba8a76b5e0.topMargin + 2>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fba8a55dc70 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' V:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fba8a76b5e0(43)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fba8a76a1d0 V:[UIView:0x7fba8a7c3490(>=150)]>"
```

)

```
Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fba8a76a1d0 V:[UIView:0x7fba8a7c3490(>=150)]>
```

I think I'm lost, because I thought with autolayout in the cells this would be easier.